# Can Visual Studio Code launch xinit as part of running or debugging Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, x11

Is it possible for VS Code to launch xinit as part of running or debugging Python?

When I run or debug right now it wants to execute the following:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder/code.py
```

My code needs X11 to be running so I get an "X11 needs to be running" error.

I can execute my code from the command line using:

```
sudo xinit /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder/code.py
```

How would I configure VS Code to add "sudo xinit" so I can run and debug directly from within the editor?

Comment: you can create a task with this command, and create a keybinding for F5 to run this task

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks. That doesn't help with interactive debugging though. How would I get the debugger to work with that?

Comment: @Ben Riga -Do you mean that you want to change the terminal that executes the code? For the running terminal, you can change the "[terminal.integrated](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows)" setting.For the [debugging terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console), it can only be set to the three existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved this by just making sure that X was started when vscode ran my app. It probably never made sense to try and get vscode to start X.